# Odd interaction of "If" and Nullable(Of Integer)

Tags: vb.net, nullable, conditional-operator

I'm using `Nullable(Of Integer)` and have just been stung by `Nothing` being cast to 0. That's excatly what I don't want when using `Nullable(Of Integer)`.

`func1` below doesn't behave as I'd expect. I can get it to do my will by ammending it (see `func2`). But I don't see why this should be necessary (and I think I might find it hard to remember to do it).

Why isn't `func1` doing what I want? I think I've encountered this before, and I'd rather not see it again.

```
Function func1(parameter As Integer) As Nullable(Of Integer)
    Return If(parameter > 10, parameter, Nothing)
End Function

Function func2(parameter As Integer) As Nullable(Of Integer)
    Return If(parameter > 10, parameter, DirectCast(Nothing, Integer?))
End Function

Sub Main
    ' Should be True
    System.Console.WriteLine(func1(11).HasValue)
    System.Console.WriteLine(func2(11).HasValue)
    System.Console.WriteLine()

    ' Should be False
    System.Console.WriteLine(func1(9).HasValue)
    System.Console.WriteLine(func2(9).HasValue)     
End Sub
```

The results I get (running this in LINQPad) are:

```
True
True

True
False
```

Answer (score 2):

Facts important in your case:

- Inline `If` method expected that both "true" and "false" expressions
  must return same type.
- `Nothing` is default value of type.
      For `Integer` it is `0`.
      For reference type it is `null`

In first method inline `If` method expects that "False" expression must return an `Integer`, because compiler cannot decide return type based on `Nothing`, it will use type produced by "True" expression. So `Nothing` will produce default value of `Integer` type which is `0`.

In second method both parameters have explicitly declared returned types, where `Integer` can be implicitly converted to the `Nullable`, so compiler will return Nullable as result of `If` method.

The key role in your problem is inline `If` method. Which uses `Nothing` as default value of `Integer`.

If you rewrite it as normal `If .. Else` then everything works without `DirectCast`

```
Private Function GetNullableInteger(parameter As Integer) As Integer?
   If parameter > 10 Then
        Return parameter
   Else
        Return Nothing
   End If
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

To explain what is happening here, I'll start by removing the shorthand part of your code which may help with my explanation.

Integers in VB.net cannot be assigned using `Null` or `DBNull`. IT can be assigned using [Nullable-of-T](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h38hb0.aspx) as you have. However, as soon as you make the object Nullable-ish, it can be evaluated to be 0.

Consider the following

```
dim x as Integer = nothing 'evaluates to x=0
```

So when your function runs, you use `DirectCast()` to return a nullable-ish Integer, which then evaluates to be not nullable by `func2`

```
Function func1(parameter As Integer) As Nullable(Of Integer)
    Return If(parameter > 10, parameter, Nothing)
End Function

Function func2(parameter As Integer) As Nullable(Of Integer)
    Return If(parameter > 10, parameter, DirectCast(Nothing, Nullable(of Integer)))
End Function

Sub Main()
    ' Should be True
    System.Console.WriteLine(func1(11).HasValue)
    System.Console.WriteLine(func2(11).HasValue)
    System.Console.WriteLine()

    ' Should be False
    System.Console.WriteLine(func1(9).HasValue)
    System.Console.WriteLine(func2(9).HasValue)
    Console.ReadLine()
End Sub
```

Comment: I'll amend my answer.

Comment: Brainmelt. Thank you @Fabio. I've stated that in my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is func1 rewritten.  Note that there is no need for casting.

```
Function func1(parameter As Integer) As Nullable(Of Integer)
    Dim rv As New Nullable(Of Integer)
    If parameter > 10 Then
        rv = parameter
    End If
    Return rv
End Function
```

The If operator, If(foo,foo=true,foo=false), should be used sparingly because it is slower than the standard If construct.

**edit:** The statement about the If operator is incorrect.

Thanks to Chris.

Comment: Do you have a source for that?  I made a simple benchmark that ran about 100000000 iterations of the code, discarding the first 1000 or so.  Result:  `If operator`: 0.0000116 ms, `If Then Else`: 0.0000093 ms.  So while the `If` operator was slightly slower, it doesn't seem to be significant at all.  The benchmarking code used a Stopwatch for its timings.

Comment: My timings in my above comment did not include using Nullable(Of Integer) or `DirectCast`.  When I changed the code under test to include that, the timings increased, but were consistent with the first test:  `If`: 0.0000345  `If Else` 0.0000333.  I surmise the increase in time was due to the `DirectCast`.

Comment: @ChrisDunaway - I may have been thinking of  IIf.